# Sending Curl http Request to Secured Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, curl, spring-boot, spring-security

I have secured Spring  Boot Application (default configuration by including spring-boot-starter-security in the dependencies).
I need to access it using **Basic authorization using Base64 format with UTF-8 CharSet**.
I'm new to spring security and don't know how to do it! the request should be something like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"XXX":["XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX"]}'  -H "Authorization: Basic b3B0dXM6Y2FuZGlkYXRlcw==" http://localhost:8080/XXX-api/search
```

I even tried this:

```
 curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H 'Authorization:Basic user:0bf582f
0-6988-42ee-9f31-d993cd83ad7b' -X POST -d '{"XXX":["XXX", "XXX", "XXX
", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX"]}'    http://localhost:8080/XXX-api/search
```

but got this error:

```
{"timestamp":1484797035123,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Failed
 to decode basic authentication token","path":"/XXX-api/search"}
```

Can some one help me and tell me how to generate the Authorization part of the curl request ?

Note: when sending a request using the browser it asks me for a username and password then works fine !

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should base64 encode `username:password`, e.g. `user:0bf582f0-6988-42ee-9f31-d993cd83ad7b`, [base 64 online](https://www.base64encode.org/)

Base64 encode: user:0bf582f0-6988-42ee-9f31-d993cd83ad7b
Result: dXNlcjowYmY1ODJmMC02OTg4LTQyZWUtOWYzMS1kOTkzY2Q4M2FkN2I

Then send the request with encode username password

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H 'Authorization:Basic dXNlcjowYmY1ODJmMC02OTg4LTQyZWUtOWYzMS1kOTkzY2Q4M2FkN2I' -X POST -d '{"XXX":["XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX"]}'`